# How to view exceptions parameters in standard flash player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Flash exceptions can provide: code,stacktrace, message and parameters. 

I.e. ( from Here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html)

> *#2121    Security sandbox violation: %1: %2 cannot access %3. This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.*

In standard flash player (Not debug) normally i see just error code.
I can configure: 
`-compiler.verbose-stacktraces=true` to see the stacktrace.

Can I somehow get the arguments as well? 
(%1, %2, %3)

Answer (score 0):

Property "message" of the Error object will return a text description of the error. The only way to read parameters is to parse a text description.

Comment: I should have probably underlined it:

**In standard flash player (Not debug) normally i see just error code**

there is no message data in standard player.